# Order list where date is string

Tags: c#, sorting

I have three classes :

```
public class QData
{ 
    public List<RData> Items { get; set; }
    public List<QDay> Dates { get; set; } 
} 
public class QDay 
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public List<RData> Details { get; set; } 
}

public class RData
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

---

my list is

```
List<QData> myList;
```

What is the most effective way to sort the list (*QData type) by Date, the Date is string.

Comment: This does not make sense.  myList is a list of QData objects that contain a list of dates.  Which date in the QData.Dates list do you want to use to sort the QData elements?

Comment: Give some example input data and expected output.

Comment: I need to sort the list by the date saved in QDay instance, which means ( i think) sort the List<QDay> Dates..

Comment: But in one `QData` there are many "Date"s, so it doesn't make sense to sort it according to "Date" - which one?

Comment: TO  Hogan : the expected is to have the List<QData> myList; orgenaized by dates every date hase its info.. thats pretty much..

Comment: Bartosz i need the  List<QData>to be orgenaize by dates.

Comment: @user2560521 - The problem is with this data model you have multiple dates for every element, there is no way to know which one to sort by.  See my answer for a suggestion for a better model.

Comment: @user2560521 do you want to sort `myList` itself, or do you mean to sort `List<QDay> Dates` of every `QData` in `myList`?

Comment: @user2560521 Use the `@` operator to reply to someone. You don't have to repeat what you have in your question, please just try to understand the fact that this doesn't make any sense. You can't sort a basing on a list of dates unless you'll define precisely the comparison between the elements. There is no obvious way to compare lists of Dates to each other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 var temp = (from e in myList.Dates
                    orderby DateTime.Parse(e.Date)
                    select e
                   ).ToList();
  myList.Dates = temp;
```

Comment: When you're writing linq in query style, I always prefer to assign the lazy executing part to the variable. It also looks good. In other words, I prefer: `var temp = from e in myList.Dates orderby DateTime.Parse(e.Date) select e);
myList.Dates = temp.ToList();`

Comment: yeah you right, you can loss the var line and write    myList.Dates = (and the linq query)

Comment: Well, `myList.Dates` will certainly not compile :)

Comment: -1 : same mistake as OP -- myList is a list.  myList.Dates is NOT valid.  Which element of myList do you want?

Comment: it does. i tested it my self.. and thanks for the -1!

Comment: @Izikon - only after you edited the question -- you can't edit the question to suit your answer.  The question is the question.

Comment: The question was added by my co-worker. So I know what she meant.

Comment: @Izikon ask herself to edit it. You can't change the meaning of the question as such.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that sort using the first date in the Dates list.  I can't imagine why you would ever want to do this but here it is.  I suspect that having Dates be a list is a mistake, in fact you only want one date there.

```
var sortedList = MyList.OrderBy(element => DateTime.Parse(element.Dates.First().Date));
```

I think this is what you actually want... ONLY ONE LIST:

```
public class QData
{ 
    RData itemInfo { get; set;}
    QDay dateInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then your sort would look like this:

```
var sortedList = MyList.OrderBy(element => DateTime.Parse(element.dateInfo.Date));
```

Comment: i need to have all dates orgenaized, not only one.. (maybe i was misunderstood..)

Comment: The right syntax should be `MyList.Sort((x, y) => x.Dates.First().Date.CompareTo(y.Dates.First().Date));` or `var sortedList = MyList.OrderBy(element => element.Dates.First().Date);`

Comment: @nawfal -- Good point, I was doing order by since sort is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
var result = myList.Select(qData => new QData()
    {
        Items = qData.Items,
        Dates = qData.Dates.OrderBy(qDay => DateTime.Parse(qDay.Date)).ToList();
    }).ToList();
```

With `DateTime.Parse` call being perhaps modified to fit to the date format in the `qDay.Date` property.

Comment: You dont need that much. Just `myList.Foreach(x => x.Dates.Sort())`. Or provide a comparer to Sort method if he wants to get it done by `DateTime` representation of the string Dates.

Comment: @nawfal Good idea, not very functional-style though.

Comment: I find linq/functional style is not the best candidate here.

Comment: @nawfal Yes, perhaps you're right. Anyway, using `Sort` is also a bit overkill here, because a custom comparer is essential here. I don't think that this question deserves so much attention :) Fell free to post your answer, I'll surely upvote it. I've noticed that it was your idea about what the OP probably wants :)